# Разная работа скрипта на компьютере и телефоне?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть у меня объект RigidBody в нем Addforce со своими значениями работает он в методе FixedUpdate. Так суть в том,что если работать в Unity и тестить игру в нем, то все ок,а вот если поставить эту же игру на телефон мой объект с неимоверной силой летает по сцене

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            _MouseControl = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right* TransformRightSpeed* _MouseControl, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

При нажатии на экран телефона (даже не двигая его) сразу же улетает..

Если кто не понял мои описания вот ссылка на видео как оно работает на практике: [Видео](https://youtu.be/k2fp9A2c968)

P.S.Честно, уже 2-3 день мучаюсь пытался обойти этот метод управления, но не помогает.Зато другое управление на похожей основе работает! Правда работает коряво и по этому нельзя использовать

```
//if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") > 0 && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    //    rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * TransformRightSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    //if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < 0 && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    //    rb.AddForce(-Vector3.right * TransformRightSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: На тему `"Mouse X"` в документации много раз написано `This is not in the range -1...1` но не сказано что именно. Вангую цифры зависят от `screens.width` и `screen.height`. И цифры скорее всего соответствуют таймингам `Update` а не `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: Так как мне быть?  не уменьшать же размер экрана?
FixedUpdate Я сделал потому-что знаю,что при работе с физикой желательно пользовать его

Comment: `"Mouse X"` вообще пользоваться нельзя. И так выдаёт 
не постоянные значения. Можно конечно `MouseX/(float)screen.width*MySpeedFactorX`, но при мультитаче он всё равно наверняка сума сходит выдавая в моменте безумные цифры.

Comment: @Yaroslav в документации как раз сказано, что выдает `GetAxis` с маппингом к мыши: `it'll be the current mouse delta multiplied by the axis sensitivity`. `Input` в принципе не должен соответствовать каким-то таймингам, его значениями заправляет внутреннее обновление движка, привязанное к фреймрейту. Физический движок в принципе не может никак повлиять на входные данные, это просто не его обязанность, поэтому в `Input` будут значения последнего после последней проверки движком.

Comment: @NitroFuNyx не совсем ясно, почему вы используете `Mouse X` в качестве оси на телефоне.

Comment: Я новичок в Юнити. По этому и пробую т.к. не опытен и просто набираюсь опыта и знаний)

Comment: @NitroFuNyx обращайтесь к другим через @, иначе о вашем сообщении никто не узнает. Советую почитать в гугле про реализацию управления под телефоны, `GetAxis` не является кросс-платформенным решением под телефоны, на консолях и пк - да.